# Como crear un diccionario a partir de una serie de elementos de selenium/beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Intento scrapear la siguiente web : https://axie.zone/finder?search=hp:61, como se puede apreciar no necesito navegar ("dando clicks") para llegar al apartado que busco el cual se puede ver en el "get" de la url: ?search=hp:61.

Basicamente ya estoy en la ubicacion que necesito, ahora es momento de obtener los datos para ello he implementado lo siguiente:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

PATH = "D:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url_to_scrap = "https://axie.zone/finder?search=hp:61"
driver.get(url_to_scrap)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

sleep(3)

#main = soup.find_all("div",class_="search_result_wrapper")

main = driver.find_element_by_id("search_result_container")

#elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search_result_wrapper")
print(main.text)

driver.quit
```

Tengo un par de lineas comentadas porque he intentado de ambas formas para poder guardar lo que me devuelve en un array o diccionario.

Tal y como lo tengo ahora mismo, me devuelve "todos" los de la primera pagina (lo cual esta bien), pero ahora lo que intento es poder hacer un diccionario para "filtrar" mejor por ejemplo:

```
K           V
Axie        313564
Meta Score  Average
price       0.065
```

Deseo almacenar los datos de estos "5" primeros por ejemplo y luego poder hacer una comparacion por ejemplo:

Si Meta_Score = Good y price < 0,05, que me los guarde y me los muestre, esto si lo entiendo seria algo como:

```
if meta_score="good" and price < 0,05:
    print(axie_code)
```

Pero.. no se realmente como almacenarlos para luego recorrerlos

Comment: Un diccionario se compone de una clave y un valor solo asigna un valor a la clave `paginas["K"] = {"Axie":313554, "Meta Score" : "Average",...}`

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Christian.

Quizas no me he expresadao bien, he editado la pregunta

Comment: Lo que te devuelve main es lo que pones, verdad?

Comment: No, lo que me devuelve es exactamente esto: 

Axie #313564
Breed count: 3
4110150
Meta Score:Average        
Stats
Ξ 0.065
[JP] Dbl Heal PVE/PVP TANK
Breed count: 2
4100190
Meta Score:Average        
Stats
Ξ 0.0699
Tank 61 HP $
Breed count: 4
3110170
Meta Score:Inferior
Stats
Ξ 0.07
PURE HEAL 2K
Breed count: 4
4120160
Meta Score:Decent
Stats
Ξ 0.07234
Yam+Wcan 6/6
Breed count: 4
4210170
Meta Score:Decent
Stats
Ξ 0.07305

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si extraes por ejemplo todos los elementos de clase `search_result_wrapper` con una línea como esta:

```
main = soup.find_all("div",class_="search_result_wrapper")
```

El resultado que obtendrás en `main` será una lista de nodos "div". Pero cada uno de esos nodos contiene a su vez dentro otro montón de elementos, que debes seguir investigando para extraer la información que te interese.

Por ejemplo, el primero de esos div (que puedes ver con `main[0]`) contiene:

```html
<div class="search_result_wrapper">
 <a class="search_result plant" href="https://marketplace.axieinfinity.com/axie/313564?referrer=axie.zone" target="_blank">
  <figure>
   <figcaption>
    <h3>
     Axie #313564
    </h3>
    <div class="subcaption">
     Breed count: 3
    </div>
   </figcaption>
   <img alt="Axie #313564" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/assets.axieinfinity.com/axies/313564/axie/axie-full-transparent.png"/>
  </figure>
  <div class="card_stats">
   <span class="nrg">
    4
   </span>
   <span class="atk">
    110
   </span>
   <span class="def">
    150
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="purity_parts">
   <div class="purity_part">
    <div class="eyes plant" title="Eyes: Confused [Plant]">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="purity_part">
    <div class="ears plant" title="Ears: Hollow [Plant]">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="purity_part">
    <div class="back plant" title="Back: Shiitake [Plant]">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="purity_part">
    <div class="mouth plant" title="Mouth: Serious [Plant]">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="purity_part">
    <div class="horn plant" title="Horn: Rose Bud [Plant]">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="purity_part">
    <div class="tail reptile" title="Tail: Tiny Dino [Reptile]">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ability_score">
   Meta Score:
   <span class="ability_score_c6">
    Average
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="small_header">
   Stats
  </div>
  <div class="stats">
   <div class="stat">
    <div class="hp" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="stat">
    <div class="speed" style="width: 17%">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="stat">
    <div class="skill" style="width: 14%">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="stat">
    <div class="morale" style="width: 40%">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui teal tag label price">
   Ξ 0.065
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
```

### Ejemplo de extracción

Vamos a fijarnos sólo en tres items de información: el nombre del bicho, su metascore y su precio. Te dejo a tí que, a partir de este ejemplo, vayas ideando cómo extraer el resto de información que te interese.

- El nombre está dentro de un elemento de tipo `<h3>` según podemos ver en el listado anterior.
- El `Meta Score` está dentro de un elemento que tiene class `"ability_score"`.
- El precio está dentro de un elemento que tiene class `"price"`.

Se puede usar `.select()` o `.select_one()`, por ejemplo, para extraer los elementos que interesan.

Por tanto podemos escribir una sencilla función que reciba como parámetro uno de estos items (por ejemplo el `main[0]` que he mostrado antes) y devuelva un diccionario con los tres datos buscados. Por ejemplo así:

```py
def extraer_info(item):
  result = {}
  nombre = item.select_one("h3").text
  result["nombre"] = nombre

  score = item.select_one(".ability_score").text
  _, v = score.split(":")
  result["score"] = v

  price = item.select_one(".price").text
  _, v = price.split()
  result["price"] = float(v)

  return result
```

Como ves, la función comienza por crear un diccionario vacío al cual va añadiendo la información que va recopilando, para retornar ese diccionario al final. Cada trocito de información puede requerir de una estrategia diferente. Por ejemplo el nombre es el contenido sin más del elemento `h3`, pero la puntuación requiere dividir el texto extraído por los dos puntos, y el precio requiere dividirlo por el espacio para eliminar el simbolito Ξ que aparece delante.

Probemos la función sobre el primer bicho:

```
>>> extraer_info(main[0])
{'nombre': 'Axie #313564', 'price': 0.065, 'score': 'Average'}
```

Parece que funciona!

### Procesar la lista de bichos

Basta ir llamando a la función anterior para cada uno de ellos. Por ejemplo así:

```
info = [extraer_info(item) for item in main]
```

El resultado sería una lista como esta:

```
[
 {'nombre': 'Axie #313564', 'price': 0.065, 'score': 'Average'},
 {'nombre': '[JP]  Dbl Heal  PVE/PVP TANK', 'price': 0.0699, 'score': 'Average'},
 {'nombre': 'Tank 61 HP $', 'price': 0.07, 'score': 'Inferior'},
 {'nombre': 'PURE HEAL 2K', 'price': 0.07228, 'score': 'Decent'},
 {'nombre': 'Yam+Wcan 6/6', 'price': 0.07459, 'score': 'Decent'},
 {'nombre': 'Axie #280235', 'price': 0.075, 'score': 'Average'},
 {'nombre': 'Axie #280257', 'price': 0.075, 'score': 'Average'},
 {'nombre': '4/7 3713 Plant 5/5/4', 'price': 0.075, 'score': 'Moderate'},
 {'nombre': 'Axie #300930', 'price': 0.07526, 'score': 'Decent'},
 {'nombre': 'Axie #311115', 'price': 0.07713, 'score': 'Decent'},
 {'nombre': 'Axie #311168', 'price': 0.0774, 'score': 'Excellent'},
 {'nombre': 'Axie #311187', 'price': 0.0777, 'score': 'Decent'}
]
```

Ahora ya tienes fácil iterar por la lista, por ejemplo buscando ciertas combinaciones de atributos:

```
for bicho in info:
  if bicho["score"] == "Excellent" and bicho["price"] < 0.08:
     print(bicho)
```

Sale:

```
{'nombre': 'Axie #311168', 'score': 'Excellent', 'price': 0.0774}
```

Comment: Excelente solucion y bien explicada, Muchas Gracias. Sin embargo, creo tener problemas con mi webdriver... O realmente no estoy seguro, porque he intentado en varias ocaciones poder "ver" el elemento main[0], pero no puedo ejecutar esa simple linea, incluso cuando intento ejecutar la funcion extraer_info(main[0]), obtengo el siguiente error : IndexError: list index out of range

Que me da la impresion que ese error es porque no se encuentra el rango.

Comment: ¿Cómo has inicializado `main`? Fíjate que en mi código lo hago con beautifulsoup y no con `driver.find_element()`. Si no te funciona, es que el html que estás intentando procesar no tiene aún la información que necesitas. Prueba a mover el parseado del soup después del `sleep()` para darle tiempo al AJAX de la página a rellenar la información.

Comment: He hecho ambas cosas, (ya habia cambiado el main antes) y ahora he movido el sleep y agregado aun mas timpo y no me devuelve nada :(